# Natural coloring for holiday ornaments instead of acrylic paint?

Tags: dye, dyeing

Interested in making crafts that would be natural coloring for diy projects around the holiday season.

webstaurantstore.com gave a lot of examples of what to use as a natural food coloring, which could also be used and incorporated into crafts done at home.

Such as using beet root powder for reds, turmeric powder for yellows, cocoa powder for browns etc.

Source: https://www.webstaurantstore.com/blog/3696/natural-food-coloring.html

**Natural coloring for holiday ornaments instead of acrylic paint?**

Comment: One approach to make existing plastic waste more green is to repurpose it. Plastic bottles come in a variety of shapes, sizes and colors.  So when something pretty is headed for your trash or recycling bin, consider slicing off the pretty parts and keeping them for future decoration projects, then put the parts that remain back in the appropriate bin.

Comment: @Lyssagal: your question, right now, looks like the beginning of a beautiful book. Judging by your reputation, you should already know that questions should be about specific problems, and should contain "enough" details. You do not describe a problem, and you do not provide details. So you (kind of) challenge us to pour out all the "science" of materials which are "eco-friendly". What do you have in mind when you say "eco-friendly"? What is the tag about? There is no kid mentioned in the question. Is it a task for kinder garden, or you want to impress your neighborhood with your decorations?

Comment: I agree with virolino, Lyssagal, and close it for needing more focus.

Comment: Thank you for the input from all comments. I wasn't sure what to put the tag as because I wanted it to be involved with creating a craft that would involve family project. I would like to elaborate more but got caught up in other work at the time and didn't get to add anymore input. Which I should have. Thank you again, I will try to elaborate more toughly the next time.

Comment: No problem, of course, Lyssagal :) Still I'd like to know what kind of ornaments you're talking about. And what do you want to use as a binder to apply the natural colourants?

Answer (score 0):

You could use yarn, even if you don’t knit or crochet you can wrap it around popsicle sticks and stuff. Dried orange slices with cinnamon sticks, star anise etc are pretty. Unfortunately I can’t think of anything sparkly. Pinterest will have tons of ideas! Merry Christmas :)